# Django template extends tag added extra space on top

Tags: django, templates

I am using Django template with the built-in `extends` tag, I didn't put too much code in it, just a nav bar, but I get extra space on top of the browser, and that can not be traced in chrome developer tools. That extra space still exists, even if, I did like this:

```
# base.html

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "css/layout.css" %}" />
</head><body>
    <div><p>something here.</p>
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

and then I extend it with just one line of code:

```
# home.html

{% extends "base.html" %}
```

Then rendered file still have this problem. I am using <strike><sup><sub>Django3.3</sub></sup></strike> Python 3.3 with Django1.6.

It was really strange.

Comment: You sure deserve an award.. Working with django 3.3 when everyone else struggling with versions 1.6 and 1.7..

Comment: embarrassing that I had such a typo, I guess I was exhausted yesterday by this little but serious problem.@AswinMurugesh

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally I find the problem was due to UTF-8 BOM in encoding.

I use Django1.6, Python3.3, on Windows7. My text editor is Notepad++, and I used to save files under UTF-8 encoding. By default, UTF-8 is saved with a byte order mark(BOM). It was this that affects the rendering of templates, at least for the tag of `extends` and `include`. Let's say, I put it in an example:

```
# home.html
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content%}
    {% include "a.html" %}
    {% include "b.html" %}
{% endblock %}
```

and

```
# base.html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- This file saved with encoding UTF-8, which is by default with BOM.-->
</head>
<body>
    <div><p>something here, base.</p></div>
    {% block content%}{% endblock %}    
</body>
</html>
```

and

```
# a.html
<p>a.html, saved in utf-8 without BOM. </p>
```

and

```
# b.html
<p>b.html, saved in utf-8, which is by default with BOM in Notepad++.</p>
```

what will be the output? It will look like this

```
___________ ( top of your browser )
            ( extra space on top, due to extended file `base.html` is with BOM )
something here, base.
a.html, saved in utf-8 without BOM. (no extra space above the content of a.html)
            ( extra space on top, due to included file `b.html` is with BOM )
b.html, saved in utf-8, which is by default with BOM in Notepad++.
```

so, basically, for any file loaded by the template, if it is with BOM, then the rendered html will add extra spaces on top of its section. Therefore, remember to save all the files with UTF-8 without BOM.

Note: I have tried earlier to use {% spaceless %}{% endspaceless %} on my `base.html` or `home.html`, but this cannot solve the problem, the extra spaces wasn't due to spaces or \n between html tags.

Comment: Thanks! If you are saving in Visual Studio, use Western European (Windows) Codepage 1252 Encoding while saving

Comment: Just curious about what's wrong with BOM... And how to save files without it in Visual Studio by default?

Comment: Basically, as I understand it, the problem is that by extending a file with BOM inside another file with BOM, you're essentially adding the BOM twice; the first BOM is then interpreted correctly by the browser, while the second one is considered to be part of the text.

Answer (score 1):

Django most recent version is 1.7 not 3.3, and your first code comment will be `base.html` not `base.py`.

You got this extra space because of you have leave space in your `base.html` file. remove the top extra space of your `base.html` file.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you might have Django 1.7, and Python 3.3 because Django 3.3 doesn't exists (and will maybe exists in a decade only :-) )

Second, extra spaces are present in the HTML rendered because Django keeps everything except tags from the template. So if you have a template like this:

```
{% load static cache compress %}  <!-- <- You have here a \n to create a new line -->
{% block htmlheader %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
     <head>
      ....
```

the rendered will interpret ths `{% load %}` tag, remove it (actually not include it) in the rendered HTML page, and continue to parse the content. Same behaviour with the `{% block %}` tag, which will leave a `\n` too. The result will be

```
<!-- A blank line due to the load tag -->
<!-- A second blank line due to the block tag -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
     <head>
      ....
```

Comment: so I am way beyond current technology, can't even imagine how Django looks in 3.3... Thanks for the edition and the answer, but I find the block tag are not sensitive to \n or space at all. It was due to Unicode BOM, I put it in an answer.